# Recurring rule query for Google Calendar API v2.0 in a particular time period

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, recurrence

I am trying to create a daily event

Like from **14-sep-2013 to 18-sep-2013 between 10:00 UTC to 15:30 UTC. daily**

I am using the following query

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20130914T100000Z\r\nRRULE:FREQ=DAILY;
UNTIL=20130918T153000Z\r\n;
```

It is creating a recursive event but for the whole day. I want event between the given time interval daily.

I am new to this. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a full day event because your DTSTART has VALUE=DATE instead of DATETIME.

Also, the UNTIL specifies the last DTSTART, not the DTEND, so you'll probably need a DTEND:20130914T153000Z

Try

```
DTSTART:20130914T100000Z
DTEND:20130914T153000Z
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20130918T100000Z
```

To break it down:

1. The DTSTART says the first occurrence starts on 2013-09-14 @ 10:00:00 UTC.
2. The DTEND says the first occurrence ends on 2013-09-14 @ 15:30:00 UTC.
3. The RRULE says subsequent occurrences occur daily and the last one will occur on or before 2013-09-18 @ 10:00:00 UTC.